# $routeProvider.when(..) not catching all URLs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, route-provider

setup: jade, angular, express, node.

In my `routeProvider` of angular, I am having some issues. I am requesting a url with a parameter which it is not catching.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

     app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider
         //... omitted some url/pages here
         //start of SPA
         .when('/dashboard/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/index',
            controller: 'dashIndexCtrl'
        })
        .when('/dashboard/class/:id',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/class',
            controller: 'classCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        }); 

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

When I call `localhost/dashboard/class/TEST`

I get redirected to root.

I declare my routes on the server side as follows:

```
app.get('/dashboard', routes.dashboard);
app.get('/dashboard/partials/:name', routes.partials);
app.get('/api/class/:id', api.classGet);
```

My controller name matches up with the `routeProvider`. In which case the controller code goes as follows:

```
app.controller('classCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
    $http.get('/api/class/' + $routeParams.id)
        .success(function(dataJson){
            console.log(dataJson);
        });
});
```

Why is `routeProvider` missing this url? I have set breakpoints within my controller so I am certain it is not being called. Also my `partials/class.jade` is not being called. Let me know if you need anymore code or directory information. Thanks in advance.

---

**After further investigation:**
If I go: `localhost/dashboard/partials/class` it will load that jade file. So it is definitely the controller.

Directory structure, I believe this is my issue now....

```
+---\
|   +---\views
    |   +---index.jade
    |   +---dashboard.jade
    |   +---\partials
        |   +---index.jade
        |   +---class.jade
```

Comment: If you are accessing address `localhost/partials/class` what is returned to browser? Code of the parsed template?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski It will just redirect me to the `/` root folder. Even when I take out the `otherwise()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into console and observe that AngularJS tries to load templates from `/partials/index` then from `/dashboard/partials/index`

### Solution

set **templateUrl** path as `/dashboard/partials/index` in config section.

### Reason: angular-route.js

```
templateUrl = $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl(templateUrl);

if (angular.isDefined(templateUrl)) {
    next.loadedTemplateUrl = templateUrl;
    template = $http.get(templateUrl, {cache: $templateCache}).
        then(function(response) { return response.data; });
}
```

There is no concatenation `templateUrl` with `route path` – just load `tempalteUrl` from Angular root of application.

Comment: I understand the reasoning for this and I made the change. However it is still redirecting me even with `/dashboard/partials/class` and `/dashboard/partials/index`, specifically when trying to access the routes `localhost/dashboard/index` and `localhost/dashboard/class`. HOWEVER `localhost/dashboard/` will load the index file...

Comment: `/dashboard/` should load template `/dashboard/partials/index` and `/dashboard/class/whoteverOrEmpty` should load template `/dashboard/partials/class`. What is redirecting you – AngularJS or Express?

Comment: Angular. It passes over `.when('/dashboard/class/:id'....` and redirects at `.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'`. When viewing my server console I can see a `GET` request for `/dashboard/class` which should not be, I should see it for `/api/class/` which is the `GET` in the controller. Thanks again.

Comment: Can browser load parsed jade templates?

Comment: try to load `/api/class/id` from browser where **id** is something that your application can handle. Is it working?

Comment: Yes it is working, my desired JSON response renders.

Comment: It was a directory issue... your clues helped me figure it out